# Migrate SQL DB to Azure SQL

Tags: azure, sql-database, content-migration

We are facing issues while moving an existing Sitecore master db from an on premise SQL Server instance to an Azure SQL Server. The BACPAC file is almost 5 GB.

[image]

The above error appears on 
- Enabling index 'ndxUnique'
- importing database
- importing package schema and data into database
- updateing database
- importing data
- processing import
- enabling indexes

[image]

Any ideas about moving such big db into azure sql would be appreciated.
It's a Sitecore 8.2

Thanks

Comment: Give a shot and download a newer version of Management Studio - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017 - as I do see the following error "A project which specifies SQL Server vNext CTP as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12"

Answer (score 2):

We regularly move our bacpacs between azure and onsite.  It is not unusual for these bacpacs to be greater than 11G.  If SSMS is timing out, you may want to try to upload the bacpac to a storage account (Blob storage), then use the portal to create the DB.

If that still bombs, then open a ticket w/Azure folks.

If that works, then it is probably not the bacpac or service level of the SQL Database you are creating.  Updating SSMS may help, but I have not experience this as an issue so I couldn't tell you it will help.

As a sidebar, I've found that it doesn't matter whether the DB is a P1 or a P15 for an export.  It takes the same amount of time +-5%.